# Adding a lambda expression or some parameters to a 'has_one' association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Let's say my models are like this:

```
class Movie
    has_one :last_rental_from_a_specific_user, :class_name => 'Rentals'
    has_many :rentals
end

class Rental
    belongs_to :movie
    belongs_to :customer
    # date of the rental attribute
end

class Customer
    has_many :rentals
end
```

How can i find all the movies and include (eagerly loaded, NOT lazy loaded) the last rental of each movie by a specified customer?

something like:

```
@x = Movie.includes(:last_rental_from_a_specific_user("jsmith")).first
@x.last_rental_from_a_specific_user.date
```

It would look something like this in SQL:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   movies left join
   (select * from rentals where movie_id = movies.id and user_id = ? and rental_date = 
      (select max(rental_date) from rentals where movie_id = movies.id and user_id = ?))       
   as tmp on movies.id = tmp.movie_id
```

Comment: Your `Rentals` class should really be singular `Rental`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you rename your `Rentals` model to `Rental`, this will eagerly load all rentals by a specified customer (in this case a user named "brian"):

```
Movie.includes(:rentals => :customer).where('customers.name = "brian"')
```

Not sure about how to then limit that to the *last* rental, though. Do you mean the last one by date?

Comment: Yes, the last rental (max date) for each movie by a specific customer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a subquery (for max date) which depends back on the Movie instance's ID, which is not available at the eager loading stage when you are querying upon the entire Model class. So, I don't think eager loading is possible.

You can create a custom view with the query you have pasted, and write a model to access the view. Then you will have multiple records for each movie with last rental date per customer and you just to have query on the record for a particular movie and customer.